# String Formatting --- Combining two separate statements into single line

Tags: java, string-formatting

Right now the lines inside the while loop "You will be charged a fee of 10 dollars " and  " Would you like to close your account?"  appear on separate lines like... 
"you will be charged a fee of 10 dollars." 
"Would you like instructions?" 
How do I change the formatting of my code so both statements are printed on a single line. The program should still work the same. The answer should appear as 
"You will be charged a fee of 10 dollars. Would you like to close your account?"

```
import acm.program.*;

public class BankAccount extends ConsoleProgram {
    public void run() {

        int bankRoll = 50;

        while(bankRoll > 0) {
            println("Currently your balance is " + bankRoll + " . ");
            println("You will be charged a fee of 10 dollars."); 
            String closeAct = readLine("Would you like to close your account?");
            if(closeAct.equals("yes")) {
                break;
            }
            bankroll -= 10;
        } /* end of while loop */

        println("your account is now closed.");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use print instead of println.

println is like print, but at the end of the String, it adds a "\n" which is the newline character.

If you want to make more than one line, you can also use print and add a "\n" where you want to have a break.

For instance:

```
print("This is an example with one line")
print("This is still in the same line as the text ahead.")
```

if you want to make 2 lines, but have 1 one String, you can also

```
print("This is an example with 2 lines" + "\n" + "but only 1 String")
```

println would make the "\n" at the end of the line so like before

```
println("This is an example with two lines") // Here is an automatically added "\n"
print ("This text is in the next line")
```

Comment: Can you edit you answer a little? I mistakenly down voted it instead of up voting it from my phone. And now it says I can up vote only if you edit it.

Comment: :) Done. On the phone the two are too close. So mistakenly clicked on the lower one. Now corrected it.

Answer (score 2):

Use `print` rather than `println` where appropriate to suppress the newline character.

Comment: what is the newline character?

Comment: @Jessica M. It's a signal to the terminal to write the next character on the following line. You'll see it as "\n" in code. println automatically suffixes the string you input with one. print doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

Prepare you string and in the end you can do

```
result= result.replaceAll("\\\\n","");
```

and then `print`.

Answer (score 1):

change from println() to print().Println() starts on a new line each time.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to use a combination of the `print` and `println` methods.

The `print` method prints the passed data, however, the `println` method **first** prints the data and **then** moves to the next line. Have a look at the [javac docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#print%28%29).

In you case you can either do -

```
print("You will be charged a fee of 10 dollars.");
```

**OR**

You can prepare your "display" statement and then print it once. However, This approach does not look good because you are printing the `Would you like to close your account?` in your `readLine` method.

Answer (score 0):

You might use something like print.
E.g. System.out.print shows the output in the same line in the console.
System.out.println shows the output in seperate lines.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
print("You will be charged a fee of 10 dollars. "); 

print("your account is now closed.");
```